# Converting Two strings to Calendar Format

Tags: android, string

Is it possible to convert two strings (one contains Date and the other contains Time) to Calendar format? I'm new to android development, please tell me if I'm asking the wrong question. Thanks in advance.

```
String txtDate = (String) txtDisplayDate.getText();
String txtTime = (String) txtDisplayTime.getText();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to convert them to a Date then you can do such like :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dateTxtDate = dateformat .parse(txtDate);

Date dateTxtTime = dateformat .parse(txtTime);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dateTxtDate);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, dateTxtTime.getHours());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,dateTxtTime.getMinutes());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,dateTxtTime.getSeconds());
```